# When making ranged spell attacks with a bow (The Ranger) do you use you dexterity or wisdom Mod?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, ranged-attack, attack-roll

So I started playing a Homebrew recently and the DM has a set of Ranged-spells attacks that require a bow (I already have one). One of the spells is as stated:

> For the duration of this spell you create two wispy arrows notched into your bow that reappear each time you attack. Whenever you attack a creature, roll an additional ranged spell attack roll and on a hit you deal an additional 2d10 force damage.

My only question is: Do I use my Wisdom Mod or Dex mod, since I'm a 12th level Drakewarden Ranger?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 18):

#### Spell attacks generally use your spellcasting ability modifier, but ask your DM.

Typical spells using attack rolls will use your spellcasting modifier, since the rules for attack rolls state:

> Some spells also require an attack roll. The ability modifier used for a spell attack depends on the spellcasting ability of the spellcaster, as explained in chapter 10.

So it seems like that is probably what is intended for the additional attack roll given by the spell, but just double check with the DM to be sure - it may be that they intend for all rolls to use dexterity since they’re still made with the bow.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a homebrewed spell, your DM should flesh out the functionality. From what you described and this part of the description:

> Whenever you attack a creature, roll an additional ranged spell attack
> roll

I assume you must make a regular attack roll using DEX and *also* a ranged spell attack using WIS.

To elaborate on what Thomas said on his reply, the intention seems to be using DEX on a single roll since it seems like it works the same as Flame Arrows:

> ...When a target is hit by a ranged weapon attack...

and Lightning Arrow:

> ...The next time you make a ranged weapon attack during the spell's
> duration (...) Make the attack roll as normal.

So for the sake of consistency it seems like it would work like those spells, but as always with homebrew stuff, you should clear that stuff with your DM